# Erro ao consultar tabela postgres usando Jpa, Hibernate e Postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Fiz um pequeno projeto para testar um pequeno cadastro em uma tabela postgres , usando jpa, com hibernate, eu consegui fazer com que a classe de cadastro funcionasse, ela insere na tabela sem problemas porém não consigo fazer a consulta funcionar pois recebo o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize

segue as calasses do projeto.

Classe CriandoObjeto

```
package com.jpapgsql.main;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import com.jpapgsql.model.Grupos;

public class CriandoObjeto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("gruposPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Grupos grupos = new Grupos();
        Float comvista = (float) 1.5;
        Float comprazo = (float) 2.0;
        grupos.setDescricaogrupo("GRUPO TESTE JPA 2");
        grupos.setComissaogrupoavista(comvista);
        grupos.setComissaogrupoaprazo(comprazo);

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(grupos);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        System.out.println("Registo Salvo com sucesso");

    }

}
```

Classe ConsultarObjetosPsql

```
package com.jpapgsql.main;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


import com.jpapgsql.model.Grupos;

public class ConsultarObjetosPsql {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("gruposPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        List<Grupos> grupos = em.createQuery("FROM Grupos", Grupos.class).getResultList();

        for ( Grupos grupo : grupos) {

            System.out.println("CODIGO: " + String.valueOf(grupo.getCodgrupo()));
            System.out.println("DESCRICAO: " + grupo.getDescricaogrupo());
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");

        }
    }

}
```

Classe de mapemento

```
package com.jpapgsql.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tgrupos")
public class Grupos implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 767902368399049708L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codgrupo;
    private String descricaogrupo;
    private Number comissaogrupoavista;
    private Number comissaogrupoaprazo;

    public Long getCodgrupo() {
        return codgrupo;
    }
    public void setCodgrupo(Long codgrupo) {
        this.codgrupo = codgrupo;
    }
    public String getDescricaogrupo() {
        return descricaogrupo;
    }
    public void setDescricaogrupo(String descricaogrupo) {
        this.descricaogrupo = descricaogrupo;
    }
    public Number getComissaogrupoavista() {
        return comissaogrupoavista;
    }
    public void setComissaogrupoavista(Number comissaogrupoavista) {
        this.comissaogrupoavista = comissaogrupoavista;
    }
    public Number getComissaogrupoaprazo() {
        return comissaogrupoaprazo;
    }
    public void setComissaogrupoaprazo(Number comissaogrupoaprazo) {
        this.comissaogrupoaprazo = comissaogrupoaprazo;
    }
```

Comment: Bom dia Ivanildo, poderia fornecer um trecho maior da stacktrace? Este erro é causado por mais de um motivo e só com o trecho disponibilizado não consigo apontar o problema.

Answer (score 0):

O único problema que vejo é haver atributos do tipo `java.lang.Number` na classe.

Isso não parece ser suportado pelo Hibernate de acordo com a documentação que encontrei, por exemplo no [manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch06.html) e no [guia do desenvolvedor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch08.html#value-basic-types).

`Number` é uma classe abstrata, base dos tipos numéricos do Java, mas que não pode ser instanciada diretamente. Repare que na hora de criar o objeto a ser salvo no banco, você está passando instâncias `Float`. Mas como o Hibernate vai saber qual tipo de número ele deve criar quando ele pegar a informação crua do banco de dados?

Esse tipo de erro pode ser associado com qualquer tipo de atributo que o Hibernate não sabe como tratar ou, pelo que já li em alguns fóruns, com anotações incorretas.